# “MYSQL: How do i put numbering? ”

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a MySQL query that will put numbering on each DISTINCT values.

```
id         name
-----      ------
1          Mark
2          Mike
3          Paul
4          Mike
5          Mike
6          John
7          Mark
```

expected result. something like this

```
count       name
-----      ------
1          Mark
2          Mark
1          Mike
2          Mike
3          Mike
1          John
1          Paul
```

Comment: not a query generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can simply use `row_number()` for this:

```
select
    row_number() over(partition by name order by id) `count`,
    name
from mytable
order by name, `count`
```

The query relies on column `id` to order the records because it seems to be unique (without a column whose value is unique within the groups, the ordering of the records having the same name is not predictable).

On earlier versions, `row_number()` can be emulated with variables:

```
select 
    case when @name = name then @cnt := @cnt + 1 else @cnt := 1 end `count`,
    @name := name
from 
    (select name from mytable order by name, id) t
    cross join (select @cnt := 1, @name := null) x
order by name, `count`
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQ62ZtgugvgaARSdNgPeh1/0)** - both queries return:

```
| ----- | -------------- |
| 1     | John           |
| 1     | Mark           |
| 2     | Mark           |
| 1     | Mike           |
| 2     | Mike           |
| 3     | Mike           |
| 1     | Paul           |
```

Comment: Isn't this actually a rank within the partition?

Comment: @Barmar: well, at long as there is a unique column for ordering (here: `id`), this doesn't make a difference. But my understanding is that, if there wasn't such a column, then we really would need `row_number()` over `rank()`; else, there would be a risk that two records of the same partition would be assigned the same rank, which is apparently not what the OP wants.

Comment: True, your solution allows for duplicate IDs, but it means that the ordering will be unpredictable. That's immaterial if you're only returning `name`, but could make a diffference if other columns are added.

Comment: @Barmar: `rank()` will not help for this. To get the numbering in a predictable order (if that matters), then we need a column (or a combination of columns, or an expression) whose value is unique within each group.

Comment: Assuming `id` is the primary key, it will necessarily be unique within the group.